# How to unit test a UI change caused by a user interaction

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm using **vitest** and **react testing library** and the situation is the following:

- I'm trying to *test whether the UI updates after a user interacts* with an input checkbox.

Then the question is: how to do it to be sure that when a user clicks the input, the parent component gets a blue border (I'm using tailwind).

The component that I'm testing:

```
export const AddOn: FC<props> = ({
  title,
  desc,
  price,
  type,
  handleAdd,
  handleRemove,
  checked,
}) => {
  const [isChecked, toggleCheck] = useState(checked);

  useEffect(() => {
    isChecked
      ? handleAdd(title.toLowerCase(), price)
      : handleRemove(title.toLowerCase(), price);
  }, [isChecked]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <div
      className={
        "relative w-full border border-n-light-gray rounded-md p-3 lg:px-6 lg:py-3 flex gap-4 items-center hover:opacity-70 " +
        (**checked ? " border-p-purplish-blue bg-n-alabaster"** : "")
      }
      *data-testid={`addon-${title}-container`}*
    >
      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          className="w-6 h-6 self-center cursor-pointer"
          *data-testid={`addon-${title}`}*
          defaultChecked={checked}
          type="checkbox"
          *onClick={() => toggleCheck(!checked)}*
          onKeyPress={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            toggleCheck(!checked);
          }}
        />
        <div className="w-8/12 sm:w-full text-left">
          <h3 className="text-base text-p-marine-blue font-bold">{title}</h3>
          <p className="text-n-cool-gray justify-self-start">{desc}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="text-p-purplish-blue text-base font-medium absolute right-2 lg:right-6">
        {type === "monthly" ? `+$${price}/mo` : `+$${price}/yr`}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the test I wrote is:

```
test("UI TEST: should show the container with a blue border after user clicks on", async () => {
  render(
    <AddOn
      checked={false}
      desc="test"
      handleAdd={() => {}}
      handleRemove={() => {}}
      price={0}
      title="title-test"
      type="test"
    />
  );

  const addOnOnlineService: HTMLInputElement = await screen.findByTestId(
    "addon-title-test"
  );

  await userEvent.click(addOnOnlineService);

  const testContainer: HTMLDivElement = await screen.findByTestId(
    "addon-title-test-container"
  );

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(Array.from(testContainer.classList)).toContain(
      "border-p-purplish-blue"
    );
  });
});
```

I tried running my test but I couldn't see the HTML updated in the test output. I got the same without the class "border-p-purplish-blue bg-n-alabaster" added because of the state change.

Answer (score 0):

My example could help but I did not using your test way.

1.import act

```
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
```

2.using dispatch event then check when text changes, testing class name

```
it("password length", () => {
    act(() => {
        render(<ChangePasswordState />, container);
    });
    expect(state).toBeNull();
    let buttonChange = document.getElementsByClassName("blue")[2];
    let txtPassword = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    let txtConfirmPassword = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
    act(() => {
        txtPassword.setAttribute("value", "1234567");
        txtPassword.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", { bubbles: true }))
        txtConfirmPassword.setAttribute("value", "1234567");
        txtConfirmPassword.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", { bubbles: true }))
    });
    expect(buttonChange.className).toContain("disabled");
});
```